# Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `data` was not specified in `Photo`. Check the render method of `withApollo(Photo)`

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

So, the above mentioned warning is generated on component page load (See attached image).

propTypes for the component are clearly specified after the component declaration.

Can anyone shed any light on this issue?

My code is as follows:

Photo.js

```html
import React from 'react';
import Comments from './Comments';
import CSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import {
  gql,
  graphql,
  withApollo
} from 'react-apollo';
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client';

class Photo extends React.Component {

incrementQuery (currentID) {

    console.log("like of id= " + currentID + " has been incremented by 1");

    this.props.client.query({
      query: queryB,
      variables: {
        id: currentID,
      },
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { post, i } = this.props;

    return (
      <figure key={i} className="grid-figure">
        <div className='grid-photo-wrap'>
          <Link to={`/view/${post.id}`}>
            <img className='grid-photo' src={post.displaysrc} alt={post.caption} />
          </Link>
          <CSSTransitionGroup transitionName="like" transitionEnterTimeout={500} transitionLeaveTimeout={500}>
            <span key={post.likes} className="likes-heart">{post.likes}</span>
          </CSSTransitionGroup>
        </div>
        <figcaption>
          <p>{post.caption}</p>
          <div className="control-buttons">
            <button onClick={this.incrementQuery.bind(null,i)} className="likes">&hearts; {post.likes}</button>
            <Link to={`/view/${post.id}`} className="button">
              <span className="comment-count">
                <span className="speech-bubble"></span> {(post.comments ? Object.keys(post.comments).length : 0)}
              </span>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    )
  }
};

Photo.propTypes = {
  client: React.PropTypes.instanceOf(ApolloClient).isRequired,
  query: React.PropTypes.object,
  variables: React.PropTypes.object,
  data: React.PropTypes.shape({
    loading: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    error: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    updatePosts: React.PropTypes.object,
  }).isRequired,
}

const queryB = gql`
  mutation updatePosts($id: ID!) {
    updatePosts (id: $id, likes: 1) {
      id
      likes
    }
  }  
  `;

const PhotoWithApollo = withApollo(Photo);

export default PhotoWithApollo;
```

PhotoGrid.js

```html
import _ from 'lodash';
import React from 'react';
import Photo from './Photo';
import {
  gql,
  graphql,
} from 'react-apollo';

const PhotoGrid = (props) => ({

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.addItem(this.refs.item.value);
  },

  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    
    if (data.loading) {
      return <p>Loading ...</p>;
    }
    if (data.error) {
      return <p>{data.error.message}</p>;
    }
    return (
      <div className="photo-grid">
        { data.allPostses.map( posts => <Photo data={{loading: true, error: false}} key={posts.id} i={posts.id} post={posts} /> ) }
      </div>
    )
  }
});

const allPostsCommentsQuery = gql`
  query allPostsCommentsQuery {
    allPostses {
      id
      displaysrc
      caption
      likes
      comments {
        id
        posts {
          id
        }
        text
        user
      }
    }
  }
`;

const PhotoGridWithData = graphql(allPostsCommentsQuery)(PhotoGrid);

export default PhotoGridWithData;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is because the component `Photo` requires a property name `data` that `isRequired`. This comes from code:

```
Photo.propTypes = {
  data: React.PropTypes.shape({
    loading: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    error: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    updatePosts: React.PropTypes.object,
  }).isRequired
}
```

You must send to `Photo` aproperty `data` with the specified shape.

Verify what does `withApollo`: does it insert `data` in `Photo`? If not, verify how is called the exported component `PhotoWithApollo`. There should be something like:

```
<PhotoWithApollo data={{loading: true, error:'my error', updatePosts:{}}}/>
```

Comment: Damien, thanks for your reply, that resolved the iessue. Yes, PhotoGrid.js imports Photo.js, as described in my amended question, and passes it the results of a graphql query.